# Archive Mac App using BoxSDK <BoxCocoaSDK/BoxCocoaSDK.h> not found

Tags: ios, box-api, boxapiv2

I have a Mac and iOS app that is using v2 of the BoxSDK.  The BoxSDK is integrated as a framework and the iOS app builds and archive fine.  The Mac app fails to archive with the following error:

Lexical or Preprocessor issue:

```
'BoxCocoaSDK/BoxCocoaSDK.h' file not found
```

The include looks like this:

```
#import <BoxCocoaSDK/BoxCocoaSDK.h>
```

I've spent a few hours of this with no luck.  I tried the following with no success:
[Lexical or Preprocessor issue when trying to archive project using the v2 BoxSDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678613/lexical-or-preprocessor-issue-when-trying-to-archive-project-using-the-v2-boxsdk)

Comment: Please check the target membership of of the files. Adding the SDK to to XCode project is not enough. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939515/xcode-target-membership-of-frameworks

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem: Build worked but Archive did not.  I solved it by adding this to the Header Search Paths in Build Settings:

$(BUILD_ROOT)/../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts

Also it was key to make that line Recursive.

Answer (score 0):

On XCode 7.1 following Header Search Path worked for me for the Release Build

$(PROJECT_TEMP_DIR)/../UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/include